# How to resolve : HttpInput idle timeout error in Jenkin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

While i am trying to update the  branch name in "**Branches to build section**", i am getting following error :

```
Also:   java.lang.Throwable: HttpInput idle timeout
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.onIdleTimeout(HttpInput.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.onIdleTimeout(HttpChannelOverHttp.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onReadTimeout(HttpConnection.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractConnection.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(HttpConnection.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.failed(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.onFail(FillInterest.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onIdleExpired(AbstractEndPoint.java:406)
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 5000/5000 ms
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Caused: java.io.IOException
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$ErrorState.noContent(HttpInput.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:318)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:256)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:484)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeTo(UrlEncoded.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractFormParameters(Request.java:555)
Caused: org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractFormParameters(Request.java:560)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:478)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1056)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.extractCrumbFromRequest(CrumbFilter.java:112)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

In which context do you see this problem ? Navigating ? Saving an item ? Jenkins CLI / REST API calls ?

To directly address this problem, you may use the Jenkins option `--httpKeepAliveTimeout` that default to `5000` (for 5 seconds) and set a higher value. See [jenkinsci/winstone](https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone/tree/winstone-5.13) for more details.

This could well be due to Jenkins being overloaded and not being able to serve resources in time.